# Prevent primefaces wizard from executing validation when using back button

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces, wizard

I have a primefaces wizard which contain a simple form and a datatable. On clicking save, the record is displayed in the datatable which is just below the form. Now for the user to move on the next tab, he should at least enter a record such that he can proceed to the next tab. So I've done a check, on clicking next , it verifies if the list use to populate the datatable is empty or not. If not he can proceed. Now my problem is on clicking back ,validation is prompted. How can I prevent this? The validation should be prompted only when clicking next.

Below is the wizard:

```
    <p:wizard flowListener="#{CarComponent.onFlowProcess}"  showStepStatus="true">

            <p:tab id="model" title="Model">

                <p:panel>
                    <p:messages />
                    <h:panelGrid id="mdl" columns="2" styleClass="grid"
                        columnClasses="label,value">
                        <h:outputText
                            value="Date" />
                        <p:calendar id="date"
                            value="#{}"
                            required="true" converter="primefacesCalendarConverter"
                            pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />

                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>
            </p:tab>


            <p:tab id="part">

                <p:panel>
                    <p:messages />
                    <h:panelGrid id="partdetails" columns="2" styleClass="grid"
                        columnClasses="label,value">
                        <h:outputText
                            value="PartNo:" />

                        <h:inputText id="partno"
                            value="#{..}"
                            required="false" maxlength="500">

                        </h:inputText>

                     <h:inputHidden
                      required="#{empty CarComponent.partList}"
                      requiredMessage="Please enter a Part." 
                       />

                        <h:panelGroup>
                            <p:commandButton image="save" ajax="false"
                                value="Save" process="@this,partno"
                                action="#{CarComponent.saveCarDetails(...)}" />
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>


                <p:panel>
                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <p:dataTable id="dta_obj" editable="true"
                            value="#{CarComponent.partList}"
                            var="currentobj" rows="15" paginator="true"
                            paginatorPosition="bottom">
                            <p:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <h:outputText
                                        value="Part No:" />
                                </f:facet>
                                <p:cellEditor>
                                    <f:facet name="output">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{current.partno}" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <f:facet name="input">
                                        <h:inputText value="#{current.partno}" />
                                    </f:facet>
                                </p:cellEditor>
                            </p:column>


                        </p:dataTable>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </p:panel>
            </p:tab>


            ...
        </p:wizard>
```

The flow listener is as follows:

```
     public String onFlowProcess(FlowEvent event) {


    if (event.getOldStep().contains("model")) {

        //some code here
    }

    if (event.getOldStep().contains("part")) {
        partList = car.getPart();
        if(partList.isEmpty()){

            String errorMsg="Please enter a Part.";

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,errorMsg, ""));
            return event.getOldStep();
        }
    }

    return event.getNewStep();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your `if` validation condition to not validate if a new step is the back one, like this:

```
if (event.getOldStep().contains("part") && !event.getNewStep().equals("model")) {
    ...
}
```

or for the first if

```
if (event.getNewStep().contains("model") {
    return event.getNewStep();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may just use a hidden input field and use the required attribute. The primefaces wizzard will validate the field on the next-button but not on the back-button.

```
<h:inputHidden
    required="#{empty CarComponent.partList}"
    requiredMessage="Please enter a Part." 
/>
```

Comment: ok I add the hidden field in the form like this :  <h:inputHidden required="#{CarComponent.partList!=null}"
        requiredMessage="Please enter a Part." />
Now I'm unable to enter a record. When i click on save, it prompts the requiredmessage. But it allows me to do back.

Comment: Exclude the hidden input from being processed, when you click the commandButton (e.g. process only the panelgrid which is containing the required information) ... beside that: Do not use the null check, use empty as I did. This will cover both, the null check and the empty check.  ....

Comment: I add it just after the panelgrid tag and still the same! how do i exclude it?

Comment: Have a look here for some example how to use the process attribute: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/process.xhtml

Comment: You should make an AJAX call to get it working. This seems to be more suitable here anyway

Comment: How to do this? Any example?

Comment: Actually it will not work because I want this validation to trigger when I click on the wizard  next button, not the save button.